# rr.com appended to URL and I don't know why

Tags: windows, internet, browser, dns, virus

I've been having some pretty bad and intermittent internet connectivity issues. I keep getting timeouts on my browsers, or what appears to be timeouts on my browsers. In Chrome it's generally `error 21`. FF it times out. And so on.

While this is happening, I can go into the command line and ping or traceroute the same domain and it works fine. I use my cellphone on the same network and it's fine connecting to the same domain. And when it fails, it's all domains that are down in all browsers, chrome, FF, etc.

I also noticed that when I try to connect to `192.168.1.1` it says in chrome did you mean `www.192.168.1.1rr.com` but when I enter `https://192.168.1.1` it's fine. It only seems to do this in Chrome. This is making me think I have a virus. I did some researching about something called road runner, but I can't find any related traces. I also ran a full virus scan using nod32 (eset) and nothing.

Any suggestion or help would be greatly appreciated. The intermittent loss of total internet access is really annoying and I'm worried about why it's trying to append the rr.com domain in Chrome. I suspect I'm dealing with two different issues, but you never know.

Also for the DNS I'm using Google's DNS servers, the famous `8.8.8.8` and `8.8.8.4`

Comment: For a second I thought the title of this question was "why".

Comment: I noticed the weird formatting too. I don't know why that is...

Comment: They've been screwing with the site CSS again...

Comment: there is a hijack that uses this rr.com thing , from some of the (gobs) of messes I was scanning over on the web it probably is part of a "package" of junk (likely to be more to it like your saying).  Here is one web link http://forums.anvisoft.com/viewtopic-53-3029-0.html (use at your own risk which means dont blindly hit download buttons etc)

Comment: I did use hijack this and went through every entry in detail. I did clean up some little things, but there was nothing obvious :(

Comment: and the hosts file? and the accelerators and search add-ons, and extentions (or by whatever name they want to call the browser plug-in type things?  And dont forget the stickey DNS cache if you fix a hosts file.

Comment: If you have a router verify the DNS servers are configured there. This isn't a "virus".  Please verify who your ISP is.  Your ISP provider is to blame for this behavior.

Comment: I also checked the host file right away. That was my first thought. Browser extensions, add-ons, you name it.

Comment: For the DNS server, it's hardcoded on the computer itself. The IP address and DNS server are manually entered.